# TYPO3 4.6 + DAM workspaces publishing => content link not rendered

Tags: file, content-management-system, typo3, workspace, dam

I've got strange behavior with dam + versionning on TYPO3 4.6.

Bug reproduction :

1. Goto a workspace without "Live editing" with a backend non-admin user.
2. Upload a file in the "Files" module of tx_dam.
3. I create a content with the user and link to the file previously uploaded.
4. If I preview the page, the link appears.
5. I go to the workspace backend module with the user, then publish my page + content.
6. I go in Live, the link is not there...

I've tested with and without the "allow edit table who don't support versionning".

**The link is still present in the backend contents but not rendered in frontend.**

TYPO3 : 4.6.16 (I know, needs updates)
DAM   : 1.3.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated TYPO3 and it's ok...